# How does one write a Cluster Spec for Distributed YoutTube-8m challenge training?

Tags: youtube, tensorflow

Can someone please post a ClusterSpec for distributed training of the models defined in the [YouTube-8m Challenge code](https://github.com/google/youtube-8m)?
[The code](https://github.com/google/youtube-8m/blob/master/train.py#L628) tries to load a cluster spec from TF_CONFIG environment variable. However, I'm not sure what the value for TF_CONFIG should be. I have access to 2 GPUs on one machine and just want to run the model with data-level parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run YouTube 8m challenge code in a distributed manner, you have to write a yaml file (There is an example yaml file provided by Google) and then you need to pass as parameter where is located this yaml file. TF_CONFIG makes reference to the configuration variables used to train the model.

For example, for running on google cloud the starting code in a distributed manner, I have used:

```html
JOB_NAME=yt8m_train_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S); gcloud --verbosity=debug ml-engine jobs \
submit training $JOB_NAME \
--package-path=youtube-8m --module-name=youtube-8m.train \
--staging-bucket=$BUCKET_NAME --region=us-east1 \
--config=youtube-8m/cloudml-gpu-distributed.yaml \
-- --train_data_pattern='gs://youtube8m-ml-us-east1/1/frame_level/train/train*.tfrecord' \
--frame_features=True --model=LstmModel --feature_names="rgb,audio" \
--feature_sizes="1024, 128" --batch_size=128 \
--train_dir=$BUCKET_NAME/${JOB_TO_EVAL}
```

The parameter config is pointing to the yaml file cloudml-gpu-distributed.yaml with the following specification:

```html
trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: "1.0" 
  scaleTier: CUSTOM
  masterType: standard_gpu
  workerCount: 2
  workerType: standard_gpu 
  parameterServerCount: 2 
  parameterServerType: standard
```